# Objective-C DEC to HEX

Tags: objective-c, hex

Hi have to convert an int value into an HEX string.

From `4` to `0x04`

From `-4` to `0xFC`

I use this code `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%02X", x]` where `x` is `int`.

With `4` I obtain `0x04`, but with `-4` I obtain `0xFFFFFFFC`.

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: it does not seem to be wrong... the `-4` is `0xFFFFFFFC` in 32bits, but `0xFC` in 8bits, mask the final result if you need it in 8bit only; but you may need to concern the possible over/underflows if the number cannot be represented in 8bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-4` of type `int` is indeed `0xFFFFFFFC` on 32-bit systems. `%02` will pad single-digit numbers with zero, but it will not truncate a longer number to two digits.

If you are interested in printing only the last eight bits, you need to mask the number yourself:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%02X", (x & 0xFF)];
```